# Jquery function remain focus in text fields in all forms even div tag displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using this function to show div tag in master page

```
$("#div_NotificationOuter").show(1000);
$("#div_NotificationOuter").animate({ bottom: '+=30px' }, 4000);
```

But in some pages  I have textfields and when this div tag display fields loosing focus.
How I remain focus in text fields in all forms even div tag displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You could monitor what was the last selected input field with this code :

```
var lastFocusedElement = '';

// This would catch any input field - so you could add your forms selector too.
// for example : $("#myForm:input")
$(":input").focus(function () {
     lastFocusedElement = $(this);
});
```

Then use the `complete` callback function from `animate` :

```
$("#div_NotificationOuter").animate({ bottom: '+=30px' }, 4000,function(){
  if (lastFocusedElement != ''){
    lastFocusedElement.trigger('focus');
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi how i  use var lastFocusedElement = '';

$(":input").focus(function () {
     lastFocusedElement = $(this);
});
 this from where i shld call

Comment: the `lastFocusedElement` at the beginning is an empty string. Once an input element gets clicked then `lastFocusedElement` will become that input.  After that you know which one was the last one clicked and you can return the focus after your animation - `trigger('focus')`.

Comment: why this will happen , its my last focus on a text field , but focus not trigering after div  was shown

Comment: is the "complete" callback function fired?

Comment: yes callback function is firing but i think this jquery function show and animation taking foucs of browser , i want to its not relate cursor focus on fields

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean... But the `.trigger('focus')` function is what is trying to return the focus to the correct input.

Comment: Hi here actually what hapening my div tag is in seperate updatepanel this conditional , and text fields in another updatepanel there is update mode is always

Comment: I don't really know asp.net so I'm not really sure what you mean by "seperate updatepanel"...